# Controlling the minimum file size in a Apache Beam/Spark Streaming pipeline

Tags: apache-beam

I have a pipeline reading from Kafka and writing to GCP. The files have too few records. I would like to create larger files. So far this is how I configure Beam (at least what I think is a relevant parameter).
My question is how can I control the size of the files produced from a Beam streaming pipeline?

```
 windowDuration: 5
 numShards: 0
 batchIntervalMillis: 30000
 checkpointDurationMillis: 30000
 maxRecordsPerBatch: 60000000
```

And here are the Spark configuration parameters relevant to streaming.

```
    spark.default.parallelism=600
    spark.ui.retainedStages=10
    spark.ui.retainedJobs=10
    spark.ui.retainedTasks=12000
    spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate=350
    spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=350
    spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches=40
    spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true
    spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=false
    spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=0
    spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown=true
    spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches=50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that when running a Beam Streaming application that if sourcing high throughput data from Kafka it is better not to coalesce the data in anyway. The reason is that when running in a cloud environment like GCP you are paying for CPU/Memory. If you try to coalesce you will be triggering a shuffle which requires for you to pay for more memory and CPU time.
What I found is that GCP already provides a way to do this. And it is described in this article ["How to concatenate sharded files on Google Cloud Storage automatically using Cloud Functions"](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-write-to-a-single-shard-on-google-cloud-storage-efficiently-using-cloud-dataflow-and-cloud-3aeef1732325). The GCP [compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) functionality was create for this purpose. It coalesce files in place. Meaning you don't have to move the data or allocate resources for that purpose. You just call the function and it all takes place in GCP servers.